# Why characters cannot be typed into this html input field?

Tags: php, html

There is a html input field text having a value from database , the value is : `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked%  onclick="" />`. In fact the data of the field is obtained using the `htmlentities` function in `PHP` on the returned column value from database.

The problem is that I cannot type any characters in the field , although the field is not read-only ! But I can delete characters in it using the back keybord or the delete keyboard.

So how can it be writable ?

Comment: Is that your exact html ? Its a radio button not a text field. So you are not supposed to write data in it.

Comment: Why do you think you can type text into a radio button?

Comment: You gotta be kidding me! How can you ever type into a HTML radio button?

Comment: You don't understand , the textfield's value is `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked%  onclick="" />` like `xxx`.

Comment: Look at my edit. I think I understand what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use radio button to write text into it. Use `type="text"` or `<textarea>`

Comment: You don't understand , the textfield's value is `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked%  onclick="" />` like `xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

its a radio button. make `type=text`

If your text field's value is `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked% onclick="" />` `<, >` are not valiud in text boxes value use `&lt;`, `&gt;` etc..

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before putting things in `value`.

Comment: You don't understand , the textfield's value is `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked%  onclick="" />` like `xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="text" id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" />` instead

**edit after my initial post:**

You need to escape the double quotes from the database using `&quot;`.

So this should works:

```
<input type="text" value="<input type=radio id=&quot;%id%&quot; name=&quot;%name%&quot; value=&quot;%valeur%&quot; %checked% onclick=&quot;&quot;/>" />
```

So, you need to escape before the database insertion or when you put the value in your text field. But in both case, double quote need to be changed.

Use php `htmlspecialchars()` for this.

Look [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrPjD/).

Comment: You don't understand , the textfield's value is `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked%  onclick="" />` like `xxx`.

Comment: I just edit my initial post. You want a textbox field and it's value is the radio field?

Comment: the textfield's value is a text , and the text is `<input type=radio id="%id%" name="%name%" value="%valeur%" %checked% onclick="" />`

Comment: Yeah, but before putting value in your field, just escape your double quotes. Or, you can change it before to put it in the DB.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but the text is stopped at `<input`

Comment: Can you paste the exact content of your db content?

Comment: yes , the Fiddle is what I want but our concept is making the creation of the field an infinite loop !

Comment: What do you mean by infinite loop? You can generate this output using a look and a db..